# How to make Ctrl+D detach tmux, while retaining GNU readline capabilities in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, tmux, readline

Based upon my days and days of researching this, I may be seeking the impossible.

#### Situation

- I have my `.bashrc` nicely configured to either spawn a new `tmux` on connect, or if one exists, attach to it.
- I *always* hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to exit a shell session. It's burned into my muscle memory. Unlearning it after thirty years of systems administration is also asking the impossible.
- **I *want* to be able to detach from `tmux` using just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, rather than having it kill my shell.**

---

#### My imperfect approach

I *can* bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to `detach` in `.tmux.conf`.

The problem is that I also have `emacs` key-bindings burned into my muscle memory, so when I start editing a command line, I'll hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to employ the GNU readline 'delete char under cursor'. Instead, the `tmux` binding swallows the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, so I'm immediately detached. Same thing if I'm editing in `emacs`.

---

#### Another flawed approach

GNU readline will take the EOF on an empty line, and then exit the shell. So I've tried trapping exit in `.bashrc` instead:

```
trap "~/tmuxexit" EXIT
```

with the contents of `tmuxexit` being:

```
tmux detach-client -s main
```

Which initially seemed like it worked, as hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on an empty line would report:

```
[detached (from session main)]
```

But `tmux ls` reports `no server running on […]`.

---

#### **Do I seek the impossible?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I crafted the simplest possible solution. This:

```
stty eof '^T'
bind '"\C-d": "\C-x\C-t\C-x\C-d"'
bind -x '"\C-x\C-t": _tmux_detach'
_tmux_detach() { [ -z "$READLINE_LINE" ] && tmux detach-client; }
bind '"\C-x\C-d": delete-char'
```

---

Explanation:

1. `stty eof '^T'` makes your terminal no longer send EOF at <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Now it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. The new key combination will behave like the old one in readline, I mean it will exit the shell only if the line is empty. I deliberately chose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> because it's very unlikely you will want to use its default binding (transpose characters) with an empty line.

   I thought that disabling EOF entirely (`stty eof undef`) would work, but it turned out readline(?) still reacts to the previously defined combination (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and makes the shell register EOF if the line is empty.
2. `bind '"\C-d": "\C-x\C-t\C-x\C-d"'` makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> "send" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. We will utilize the two sub-sequences separately.
3. `bind -x '"\C-x\C-t": _tmux_detach'` – From now on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> executes `_tmux_detach`…
4. … which is a function that detaches `tmux` if the line (`$READLINE_LINE`) is empty.
5. `bind '"\C-x\C-d": delete-char'` – From now on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> deletes the character at point, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> usually does.

---

So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will work like this:

- if the line is not empty, the function is a no-op and `delete-char` does its job;
- if the line is empty, the function does its job and `delete-char` is a no-op (it gets triggered but has nothing to do).

---

Notes:

- `READLINE_LINE` was introduced in Bash 4.0.
- If you paste the code into your `~/.bashrc`, you may want to improve it: check if the shell is inside `tmux` before changing the behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, so shells outside of `tmux` are unaffected.
- It's important that `_tmux_detach` acts before `delete-char`. If you reverse the order then you will introduce a bug: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> that deletes a solitary character will also detach `tmux`.

Comment: You sir, are a steely-eyed missile man. This works perfectly. The impossible is possible. I'm indebted!

Answer (score 1):

[Kamil Maciorowski's](https://superuser.com/users/432690/kamil-maciorowski) answer shows it's possible, and I thank him. Per his mention of testing if one is in a tmux to determine the ctrl-d behavior, the following *seems* to work as desired, so I am expanding on his answer.

The tests within .bashrc:

- If not in a tmux session, don't remap keys
- If a tmux session exists, attach to it, retaining the remapped keys
- If not, create a new session employing the new keys

```
if [[ "$TERM" != "screen-256color" ]];then
    if tmux has-session -t main 2>/dev/null; then
        tmux attach -t main
    else
        tmux new -s main
    fi
else
    stty eof '^T'
    bind '"\C-d": "\C-x\C-t\C-x\C-d"'
    bind -x '"\C-x\C-t": _tmux_detach'
    _tmux_detach() { [ -z "$READLINE_LINE" ] && tmux detach-client; }
    bind '"\C-x\C-d": delete-char'
fi
```

Note the use of "screen-256color" (set by adding `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` in .tmux.conf). If you don't wish to use the extended color map, you can simply declare "screen" instead in the .bashrc snippet.

The above may be more specific to my preferences than it needs to be - it is most certainly not the only way to do these tests, but it works for me.
(updated to a smarter construct)

Answer (score 1):

Zsh version..

```
# tmux detach or delete
function _delete_or_detach() {
    if [[ -n "${BUFFER}" ]]
    then
        zle delete-char-or-list
    else
        tmux detach-client
    fi
}
if [[ -n "$TMUX" ]]
then
  setopt ignoreeof
  zle -N _delete_or_detach
  bindkey "^D" _delete_or_detach
fi
```